# Template tag Django

Tags: django, django-templates

How to use template tag in Django template?

```
{% if proposal.status == 'c' %}
  <td><i class="fa fa-close fa-fw status-cancelado"></i></td>
{% elif proposal.status == 'elab' %}
  <td><i class="fa fa-circle fa-fw status-elab"></i></td>
{% elif proposal.status == 'p' %}
  <td><i class="fa fa-circle fa-fw status-pendente"></i></td>
{% elif proposal.status == 'co' %}
  <td><i class="fa fa-check fa-fw status-concluido"></i></td>
{% elif proposal.status == 'a' %}
  <td><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw status-aprovado"></i></td>
{% endif %}
```

I use the below code, but return error.

```
from django import template
from django.utils.html import mark_safe

register = template.Library()


@register.tag
def status_icon(status):
    icons = {
        'c': 'fa-close status-cancelado',
        'elab': 'fa-circle status-elab',
        'p': 'fa-circle status-pendente',
        'co': 'fa-check status-concluido',
        'a': 'fa-star status-aprovado'
    }
    return mark_safe('<i> class="{}"</i>'.format(icons[status]))
```

But return error. ...................................................................................................

[image]

Comment: What is the problem with the code you've shown? Does it work? If not, what kind of error it produces?

Comment: I want refactor for reduce the code using templates tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would end up with something like this:

```
# yourapp/templatetags/yourapp_tags.py
from django import template
from django.utils.html import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def status_icon(status):
    icons = {
        'c': 'fa fa-close fa-fw status-cancelado',
        'elab': 'fa fa-circle fa-fw status-elab',
        # etc
    }
    return mark_safe('<i class="%s"></i>' % icons[status])
```

Example usage:

```
{% load yourapp_tags %}
<td>{% status_icon proposal.status %}</td>
```

Comment: My personal opinion is that in this specific case the template tag must fail, as otherwise it would produce an incorrect markup. But you're right, in many cases we should implement some sort of default icon.

Comment: What's the full path and name of the file where you put the templatetag code to?

Comment: myapp/templatetags/core_status_tags.py

Comment: Make sure you have the `myapp/templatetags/__init__.py` file and `myapp` is in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: see my code on the [GitHub](https://github.com/rg3915/orcamentos/commit/d36ee49b75c7de555aeb83dd94f7c92cba5dc6a7)

Comment: Code looks fine. Did you restart your server?

Comment: OK, its work. Now `status_icon() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`.

Comment: Sorry, the decorator should read as `@register.simple_tag`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks you for help.